# GoogleQuery returning output in one row only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm using query but the output is weird. I just copied this sheet and the original file is working properly. As you can see in the output are all stuck in one row but it should be a three or more row base on the reference. The code is literally copy paste, no as in the whole sheet is made from "Make a copy" function of googlesheet then i just renamed the file. Is there any fix to this? Thank you!
my code : `=QUERY(Main!A:AO, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, AN, AO where J ='A'")`

[image: invalid query output]

Answer (score 1):

Use the (optional) headers argument: use 1 if you want a header row, 0 if not.

See if this works

```
=QUERY(Main!A:AO, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, AN, AO where J ='A'", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can leave it empty (after comma) which equals to have `0` there

```
=QUERY(Main!A:AO, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,AN,AO where J ='A'", )
```